# How to pass a width of a div as an angular input

Tags: javascript, angular

i want to pass the width of a div in the style attribute as an input but my code gives an error :

```
export class FieldErrorDisplayComponent {

@Input() errorMsg: string;
@Input() displayError: boolean;
@Input() width: string;
}
```

html :

```
<div *ngIf="displayError" >

<span class="sr-only">(error)</span>
<div style="{{width}};padding:5px 5px 5px 15px !important" class="error-msg alert alert-danger">
  {{ errorMsg }}
</div>
```

HTML :

```
 <app-field-error-display [width]="55%"  [displayError]="isFieldValid('dateDepart')" errorMsg="Choisissez une date.">
                    </app-field-error-display>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div [style.width]="width"></div>
```

Or this if you sent only the numeric value:

```
<div [style.width.%]="width"></div>
```

More info here: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`<app-field-error-display [width]="'55%'"  [displayError]="isFieldValid('dateDepart')" errorMsg="Choisissez une date.">
                    </app-field-error-display>`

use single quotation `[width]="'55%'"` to pass value